# UILocalNotification is there a system cache?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have an iOS application that I use scheduleLocalNotification to create notifications for the user. My question is, when the notification appears, if the user taps on it my application can process it. But what happens if the user has no interaction with the notification. The notification will disappear. Is there any way inside the application to determine that notification was sent? Is there a system queue that the application has access to?

Answer (score 0):

'The notification will disappear',

> By default its not get disappear until an unless user remove it from
>   the notification bar.

Is there any way inside the application to determine that notification was sent?

> Yes, its possible to do it by programatically. You need to query
>   [scheduledLocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications). You will get array & then you can
>   write your logic for checking.

Is there a system queue that the application has access to?

> Yep, Using [scheduledLocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications) you can do this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. scheduledLocalNotifications will give you a list of notifications that are ready to be sent at some future date. I'm looking for a list of notifications that were sent but user didn't respond to (i.e. Clicked on it to activate).

Comment: One thing you can do is, Store the notification data in your database with one flag = 0, If user responded to notification & application get opened then you can update that flag to 1. If not then you when user directly open the app then you can check that flag=0. Does this will work?

Comment: I understand what you are suggesting and was thinking along the same lines. I'll give it a try. Thanks.